# Spotfire 7.0 Web Player Javascript API customizations issue

Tags: spotfire

When using the Web player Javascript API I cannot get the .Customization properties to be applied on the Spotfire 7.0 web player.
When I use the identical html script in Spotfire 6.0 Web Player the customizations for Hide toolbar and Hide status bar disappear as expected (see below).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

ps. I noticed that the .open parameters for the Parameter Configuration Block 'SetPage(pageIndex = 2);' also fail to be applied in my 7.0 web player but do work on 6.0.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=6.0"></script>
 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function()
  {
  var wpCustomization = new spotfire.webPlayer.Customization();
  wpCustomization.showToolBar = false;
  wpCustomization.showStatusBar = false;
  webPlayer1 = new spotfire.webPlayer.Application("http://spf2/spotfireweb/", wpCustomization);
 
  webPlayer1.open('/Information Model/Analyses/Operations/Operations Management Dashboard/Dashboard Mockup','Dashboard','SetPage(pageIndex = 2);' );
  }
</script>
</head>
<body >
  <div id="Dashboard" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please apply the latest hotfix; I think this was fixed in HF001:

`TSWP-8143 - Customization settings in javascript mashup code is not applied correctly.`

you can get the hotfixes and installation instructions at http://support.spotfire.com/patches_spotfire.asp#spotfire70